# Why use a reverse proxy to access a MongoDB Atlas database

Tags: reverse-proxy, mongodb-atlas

My MongoDB Atlas (hosted in AWS) is only access by my AWS Lambda functions.  There are no other applications that access my MongoDB.

I have been told I must use a reverse proxy but not why I must use a reverse proxy.

I understand that a reverse proxy adds security by preventing someone from accessing my MongoDB directly.  But that is not possible because all connections come from my Lambdas.

For my situation, what reasons are there for me to require the use of a reverse proxy to access my MongoDB?  What benefits are available if I use a reverse proxy?

Comment: Are you currently connecting to Atlas via Lambda now? If so, how are you managing the whitelist?

Comment: Lambdas are in a VPC and NAT gateway is providing static IP

Comment: I'm really struggling to come up with any rationale as to why setting up a reverse proxy in your vpc to protect a db in another vpc would be a good idea. The whitelist was the only problem I could see it solving and I prefer your NAT Gateway solution for that anyway. Is it possible that this is a legacy design pattern that was fit for purpose when introduced, but not so much in this environment?

Comment: @KMo  Yes.  Seems that the reverse proxies are not required for my situation.  If the Lambdas were moved out of the VPC, the proxies running inside the VPC would provide a way to whitelist.  Thanks for your help.  If you want to provide an answer, I will accept it.